# VHDL signal assignment within a process not behaving correctly?

Tags: vhdl

Here's the code I'm running

```
architecture arch of func
signal sig_s1: std_logic;
begin
process(d1,d2,d3)
 begin
   sig_s1 <= d1 and d2;
   res2 <= sig_s1 xor d3;
 end process;
end arch;
```

You would expect that **res2** would always use the previous value of **sig_s1**, but in simulation it's working with the updated ones, as if this was a sequential code. What gives?

Here's the waveform https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSXpc.jpg  (res1 is the result if I used variable instead of the signal for sig_s1). I don't know how benchmarks work.

Comment: show the full code with testbench please. if d1,d2 and d3 are all changing at the same time, then res2 should be using the old value.

Comment: Signal assignment is behaving correctly, but there's a mistaxe in the process sensitivity list.

Comment: Which signal in a right hand side of an assignment is not present in the process sensitivity list?

Comment: @user1155120 Why does sig_s1 need to be in the sensitivity list? It didn't help in this case, btw.

Comment: @BrianDrummond If you could take a look at my comment above...

Comment: I looked at it. As Vipin says, show the full code and testbench too, not just a code snippet.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I've made some edits.

Comment: The edits don't help, especially since the signal names don't all match the waveform. What gives? You need to write a testbench and learn how to simulate properly, that's what gives. Once you can make this question an [MCVE] someone can help you, if you haven't figured it out in the process.

Answer (score 3):

What gives is that signals do not get updated until all the processes have suspended.

Suppose there is a change (an *event*) on one or more of `d1`, `d2` or `d3`. They are in the sensitivity list of the process, so the process starts executing.

1) First this line gets executed: `sig_s1 <= d1 and d2;`. This is a line with a signal assignment in it (`<=`). The effect of executing any line with a signal assignment in it is, if the value of that signal is to change, to schedule that change for sometime in the future. If no delay is specified (which is the case here), then that future time is the next iteration of the simulation, which will occur once all the processes have finished executing (have suspended).

2) Then this line gets executed `res2 <= sig_s1 xor d3;`. Since, the effect of executing the previous line was to schedule a change on `sig_s1` for the future, **the value of signal `sig_s1` has yet to change when this line is executed**. That is really, really important. Hence the bold type. Consequently, the previous value of signal `sig_s1` will be used to evaluate the expression `sig_s1 xor d3`. If this results in a change to signal `res2` then that change will be scheduled for the next simulation iteration, too.

There are various solutions to your problem. The simplest is to add signal `sig_s1` to the sensitivity list:

```
architecture arch of func
signal sig_s1: std_logic;
begin
process(d1,d2,d3,sig_s1)
 begin
   sig_s1 <= d1 and d2;
   res2 <= sig_s1 xor d3;
 end process;
end arch;
```

Then once any change on signal `sig_s1` is actioned, the process is executed again (because signal `sig_s1` is now in the sensitivity list. This line will be executed first `sig_s1 <= d1 and d2` and, assuming signals `d1` and `d2` haven't already changed again, there will be no change to signal `sig_s1`. Then the line `res2 <= sig_s1 xor d3` will be executed immediately afterwards. Signal `sig_s1` will now have its new value and so the value of signal `res2` will be updated (on the next simulation iteration, as before).

However, I recommend you don't do that. You don't need a process at all with simple expressions like this. It would be much better to do away with the process and just use *concurrent signal assignments*, like this:

```
architecture arch of func
signal sig_s1: std_logic;
begin
  sig_s1 <= d1 and d2;
  res2 <= sig_s1 xor d3;
end arch;
```

Each concurrent signal assignment (as the name suggests) runs concurrently and so is a process in itself. (So, now there are two concurrent processes). With a concurrent signal assignment, you get a sensitivity list for free. So, there is no possibility of missing a signal out of the sensitivity list. Not only that, it takes up less space on the page, which means that the reader can see more of the code at once and hence get a better understanding*.

**Always implement simple combinational logic like this as concurrent signal assignments, not as a process.**

*I'm a prolific commenter, which rather undoes that advantage. Ho hum.